# How to get sum of duplication count value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following below table:

```
CandidateId   CandidateName
  can132        Mazhar
  can132        Mazhar
  can133        Raj
  can133        Raj
  can134        Rahul
  can134        Rahul
  can134        Rahul
```

My SQL query base on candidate id getting duplication.

```
SELECT CandidateId, COUNT(*) as duplicate
FROM Table_CandidateInfo_Preview
GROUP BY CandidateId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY CandidateId
```

Right I am getting below output:

```
CandidateId     duplicate
 can132         2
 can133         2
 can134         3
```

I need result like final value `4` to send my output parameter in my stored procedure because three Candidate Id have duplication and `cand132` 1 time, `cand133` 1 time and `can134` 2 time. Sum of all will get `4`value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your query up in a derived table (slightly adjusted). SUM its duplicate values:

```
select sum(duplicate)
from
(
    SELECT CandidateId, COUNT(*) - 1 as duplicate
    FROM Table_CandidateInfo_Preview
    GROUP BY CandidateId
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) dt
```

Comment: Thank you very much. @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want:

```
SELECT SUM(duplicate - 1)
FROM (SELECT CandidateId, COUNT(*) as duplicate
      FROM Table_CandidateInfo_Preview
      GROUP BY CandidateId
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) c;
```

I want to note that if you had a unique id for each row, then you could also do:

```
select count(*)
from Table_CandidateInfo_Preview cip
where cip.id > (select min(cip2.id)
                from Table_CandidateInfo_Preview cip2
                where cip2.CandidateId = cip.CandidateId
               );
```

To me, this seems like a more direct count of the "duplicates".  I should also note that some databases (such as SQLite, Oracle, and Postgres) have row identifiers of one form or another that can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(result.duplicate) AS Summary FROM (
SELECT CandidateId, COUNT(*) as duplicate
FROM Table_CandidateInfo_Preview
GROUP BY CandidateId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as result
```

1. Try This I think it will help